# C++ ConvexHull of points algorithm (and their indices)

Tags: c++, algorithm, convex-hull

I need to implement a  C++ code that computes a ConvexHull of points and returns the indices, I couldn't find a way to do it in C++?

in Matlab and Python it's very easy you just need to pass an array of points to ConvexHull function and it returns the indices; do we have something equivalent in c++?

Comment: No, C++ doesn't have a builtin function for that. It should be easy to find code for that online though. Since your question is not about programming, it is off topic. Please delete it.

Comment: the convex hull algorithm uses the external product of point-by-point (effectively sorts by angle) to find points on the convex hull

Comment: When I implemented convex hull in C++, I followed this guide in C#: http://loyc-etc.blogspot.com/2014/05/2d-convex-hull-in-c-45-lines-of-code.html

Comment: There is computation geometry library for C++, CGAL, link http://www.cgal.org/. It does hall Convex Hull implementation

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get the convex hull indices for point clouds in C++ and was also annoyed by the fact that the functions provided by PCL or Boost don't return the indices of the points. And you're right that the QHull documentation seems quite complicated. So I went to look at the [PCL source codes](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/convex_hull.hpp) and extract it myself. Here's what I got

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <qhull/qhull.h>
}

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud; // some point cloud
int dimension = 2, size = cloud->size();
coordT* points = reinterpret_cast<coordT*> (calloc (size*dimension, sizeof(coordT)));
for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    points[2*i] = static_cast<coordT> (cloud->points[i].x);
    points[2*i+1] = static_cast<coordT> (cloud->points[i].y);
}
int exitcode = qh_new_qhull(dimension, size, points, true, const_cast<char*> ("qhull FA"), NULL, NULL);
if (exitcode != 0 || qh num_vertices == 0)
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: qhull was unable to compute a convex hull for the given point cloud" << std::endl;
}
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr hull_indices (new pcl::PointIndices());
vertexT * vertex;
FORALLvertices
{
    hull_indices->indices.push_back(qh_pointid(vertex->point));
}
qh_freeqhull(!qh_ALL);
int curlong, totlong;
qh_memfreeshort(&curlong, &totlong);
```

Note that this is for 2D point clouds. For other dimensions or data types, you can modify it accordingly. Hope that helps!

Comment: amazing, before accepting this I need to find time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

[QHull](http://www.qhull.org/) is the defacto standard for convex hulls, Delaunay triangulations, and friends. QHull offers a number of languages and interfaces - plus the page links to some very good references.

Comment: I saw QHull but it seems very complicated I couldn't find a straightforward way to cull ConvexHull function in my C++ file